# how can I solve pyhon error : local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, global-variables, local-variables

```
global max_n
max_n = 0

def dfs(_n, cnt, length):
    if cnt == length:
        print(a)
        total = 0
        for i in range(cnt):
            total += int(a[i]) * (10 ** i)
        if total % 30 == 0:
            if total > max_n:
                max_n = total
```

If I use this code, then there is error in  `if total > max_n:`.

Even though global variable `max_n` is in line 1, why did this error happen?

And could you teach me how to debug this error case?

Comment: Where did you initialize `a`? Which values you used for `_n, cnt, length`?

Comment: Your code returns `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`. If you have defined `a` somewhere else, you should show that in your code, and also provide how this function is called.

Answer (score 1):

I already had a problem like this,
this is because the function only searches the variable in the function.
Try this code:

```
max_n = 0

def dfs(_n, cnt, length):
    global max_n
    if cnt == length:
        print(a)
        total = 0
        for i in range(cnt):
            total += int(a[i]) * (10 ** i)
        if total % 30 == 0:
            if total > max_n:
                max_n = total
```

Comment: This is what I want! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I am happy to be able to help you :)